# Are there locally compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which are not compact?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

Are there locally compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ tht are not compact?

> A set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is **compact** if it is closed and bounded.  Every infinite set $\{ x_n \}$ has a subsequence $\{ x_{n'} \} \subseteq \{ x_n \}$ such that $x_n \to x \in X$.

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ all the definitions of compact we can think of are the same.

> A set $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ is **locally compact** if every $x \in X$ has a compact neighborhood.

Are there locally compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are not themselves compact?

Comment: any open subset?

Comment: @Thomas I have to think about that.  These exercises always make my head hurt.

Comment: no need to wait for the headache, I've written an answer as explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Could as well make the comment an answer. Any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is locally compact: let $U$ be such a subset and $x\in U$. Since $U$ is open, there is an open ball $B_r(x)\subset U$. So $\overline{B_{r/2}(x)}\subset B_r(x)\subset U$ is a compact neighbourhood of $x$ in $U$.

Comment: Dangit, I'm a slow typer . . . +1.

Answer (score 1):

How about $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself? Do you see how to construct compact neighborhoods of arbitrary points? (HINT: closed balls . . .)

Comment: As a further exercise, show: a space $X$ is locally compact iff every open subset in $X$ is locally compact. This connects my answer with the other two.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}^n\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed, locally compact, and countable, but not compact.  You can have a bounded, locally compact, countable subset which is not compact too: $\left\{\frac1k\,\big|\,k\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}\right\}^n\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$.